# Scanner API for iOS

Tags: ios, api, pdf, jpeg

I'm looking for a scanner API library to be embedded in a new app I'm developing in order to give it the feature of scanning documents (in PDF or other formats) using the built-in camera of the iPhone/iPad. Is anybody aware of such a library (...available for free or cheap...of course). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are looking for an Optical Character Recognition (OCR) iOS SDK.

There is 2 basic type of OCR SDKs: offline and cloud based.

Here is a few options:

- [ABBYY](http://www.abbyy.com/mobileocr/) ,which is a great OCR engine, they have an offline and a cloud base solution too. So far it is the best OCR engine for iOS, very good performance and very good precision, but they are not cheap. You have to contact the sales team, and provide information for about your project for a demo SDK.
- [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), [iOS Wrapper here](https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios), which is Google's Open Source project. It is free, but it has way worse performance than ABBYY's engine. It is very flexible, and has a big community.

Also there is some more, but I don't have any experience with these:

- [Pixelnetica](http://www.pixelnetica.com/products/document-imaging-sdk/document-imaging-sdk-features.html)
- [OCR Api Service](http://ocrapiservice.com)
- VeryPDF Cloud

First you should let the user take a good photo of the desired document, crop and scale it for the most accurate picture, and after that submit it to the OCR engine.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The [Genius Scan SDK](https://www.thegrizzlylabs.com/document-scanner-sdk) allows developers to integrate a document scanning module into mobile apps. Both iOS and Android.

It's a full–fledged image processing SDK rather than an API as it includes the core features needed for capturing documents on mobile (edge detection, distortion correction, multiple types of image amelioration and PDF/JPEG generation). It doesn't require installing third-party apps.

SDK is native for iOS and Android, and doesn't support OCR at this time. It's derived from the application of the same name, which provides a good preview of the SDK (free on both app stores).